# Converting Data to String in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to convert a piece of `Data` to a `String` but am running into issues. My data, which is stored in a variable as `d` has the following debug information.

```
Printing description of token:
▿ Optional<Data>
  ▿ some : 2281 bytes
    - count : 2281
    ▿ pointer : 0x0000000150810410
      - pointerValue : 5645599760
```

I am trying to save it to a String defined at `var string:String?`

```
self.string = String.init(data: d!, encoding: .utf16)
```

I have tried using `.utf8`, `.utf16`, `.utf32`, `.ascii` as encoding types by no matter what I try `self.string` is equal to `nil`. Any thoughts?

Edit 1: When using `.unicode` I get some lovely crazy output. So, I'm close, just not close enough.

```
 Ȁ\0急୏勳锢湝ѐ�逸볶뾖択ੲ㣩⁝痲購�㖦夫븅誜ྎ�⫋柯띴霜ꑟ綅橩侱맄ஔאַ穚钘뀄燝㒍怌ᝎໟໜ隩쭡껶⺙�ﲽ셦⊫◦�켮٪ᓦ܋贒酏쫇㑖�ꓷꩾ伈\0נ耙襘᪬Ⅲ탼᱀雬�逥栦ᡷㆸ翅⼦鲣䆗꿨翾㰁㭝쬝錟ℕ쮕랐붲훒㲫갆ꆳ룻⋭ꈉ㻕x儀쨠桪ﱀ픍漚㹨䘗쪃枏ݢ蜫北��ᒲ쥹푥詜ል꟝퉯�笑盞鼊㹉긴㒰뫾뼋繐☟㉽莭ꝇ晴ឃ촴Ⲷ鴚餁泸곶ᜇ劋ഖ卫⻍泊櫶踶㫮쿶ߠ迲긆擺迹虡ཟ融㦆唿泤垎혣䶢桙䜨壖깚᤽꽻䪭₭ᱚ㱚䙳ഘ體䊘멷�肯鋫ꕶ䉿㘳ꐨꅴ㸒꼋龛㕒럄ﳵ풭ᑀ垢ꘞ㺼㠖꺮ꙧ깳撤呄醰뜧䅉纴⺥㸿蚄츣긣ᮕ耻䓽⁙婁䝒熨ﵕ�㖆�嫨뉋鶝ᱨ닊궟ꦈﶱ혁୦켱概ꔩⴆ�䗞ዻ鲔峢ꈕ仞몋襲䮧ꀹ灕뒓ᎋサ癪ꥱ咑ꝏ㥀洹ݑ쀉荏猓緊ꏘ顙ધ瘦㲘퀻ે㉁ṀₖꉟᏜ쯓㆔滘䲱䈔倁♠닡䥞챵긎뎄褈ﳛ쎈宊沉ិ盌ﮈ桠¼죪뵂䞄쯉薛妤ի帮럊厀쾏瞃尡貙⻥띈ર㽩瘠캹낅쯯촧㔮�泌ூ鯿䂼�왓㨅彛迁泮ĩ炭떧㈧鐾ᦋꮂ荗꣓窍㮱竐芶ￋ굑㞣썵ﴕ쳱烏큏䯎ꚽ⑷嚱⊒퐅ᆎ韺蟑⊓굠阶쯣愮㋆浡䛢簸疢ꞛ룇๙眚飀䱭♇ካ㮏좾銉韒巜꬟쇼⳪ｙ믗瀮∦ﳁ솖⁛檹뤪랁䂿푅⨂৭䳐嘠渆࿫ࡱ敮⏃㮭䳄彤脸ᷧ扛ꀺꖽ䅉峵㻉篪�핞뤝桴ᛳ莏흹訖ف뵌ኖ쳹㈕舞篠ꑢფ栘ᳬ茹貘郁ᒡ끦ᴙ⁒茰쓉괷莶ꙏ庹꾢ᣂ䶛朾莊畀缾蜿萗쏵꾺檜嬹躊拾疻군붹க㢝傅릣鰭癝ﱯⳆꁜ�䍴�抄㢻돣寞丠纡췺国ᚂ憐쾜䷕　뙳䏶Ꭴ㮜㍋蹷ಚ蓥ᯐオЀ븚猊訓溣웺䇚ﮓ憹軡풬铏຦퓙亶빑⁓珈縛瘐檢譔檹簩㱍⹺哋讪⚝䖬꫇䑐㭪\"駱臹୏몮ڷ뼿㥽趘鹋ⅿ䰝ᨘ枙ˇ粮䃷ᵱ᳓৭潥Ⲡ릮꠪兞�᩺潝ꐧ萇쉣蔫䀎૜ᬋ嵴ꧽ㧝뫲躱딺岻텘ᦉ窰硾꓍睠줕㶧搮뛇Ẇ㖘욎铣䀙䇿糴Ⱓ㞱ഴ쭷ᔌጼ⏯䜘췠Ȉ株⍜멾쓄ⶣ붆쯯➣롞궡枪딭碡㙦集ತ⡓罠啫չ礂ᐈ崔ོ肝⋄⹵煨큾Έ迡ጿ柜폻Ṻ枚謧뙥辅ꔊ㩩ꯡ�钇㟥禜柜調厅岦Ⲩ철ᡶ颜쎝亨⬒닜䄐쐨Ꞌ劬䉄མᑤꚖ篏៽㮬㾚펣쀙簌➄髙삣╄⺺錒ᵡ쯧콨⺫夦齲쨗⋿㛄ݧᆁ탿骅ⵚ樱拐ⶡ딚覈紭ꇗ挐攆㶮籭㡌ሃ鵆叉刞ꦾ�倰ጳᴈ譮翦ꈬ羏ḗ䗺乽ሊ嫩Ⴑ欮根嗚ྍ⟦剜꜖秶우対蟳餶ㆽ苯쐞๞§뱅㪺壭㼊꛵㷷ᶾ坾෦鲐踓ゞ鎰捯漋࣍隳ꔜ醛胞轖⤭껉뉸Ȱ핂췴멋䵆﹂荂与᷼槣Ọ斌䁔ట萖ℿ䦦�ワ䉠ꎠౘ�⸗喂褶멊군ｪ謷⒴�蟺胨嫗皷啤즎⩕뼲티蝟㡸鱙酝䷈穉跰皐鸙ꢉ녷䭣컨泣哊⭎鷌隆ȭ톱浴ᎅ⍙蚴蠟䰲ꑭ䲰鉉�뛉綂琄ꚛＬ鸙ꗄ黏坔ぅ팆晟ꌽ骋쎆ꅃ䂍�쑯퉼⒈།蠰雭핀辫岏䳭쫱罡툏겞㱯綥ࠦ鹶흁妜遊엛﫫㰆ꝍ䄱࿅�林㑰�먒ᘛ⌈吁ຶᒅ셛䢋░塂ੇ⻵묦滏彾㤮螹昮䧫巋Ұᨧ⊱달㚘䀡닡뒵蹡堕聋裕㗶搡ᘵ휲ꥅ൩羢异貗Ᏸ㲬諙桋禜ꃄ燊煶걋୎ˢ㔦ꩤ䨟ꀋ鎧엕玜㞄兺ܨ叟ൕ殄䇀�쏤㶦㮆焤ᳶ﫴咑傖作ﶽ鏐⦪쟥⯄⦗ৠ䊗폜鿂壊缬ꢤ퇏ॽﯨ띌晉ﮬ趆⫹푡綎囿닽㲁㐮쒁﮺㗺▿팢젶→䩡﩯ᗁ쾰殇ﺎ亹㽧㴬쎜ꦏ微봙▘㕾◯뜳令휀仏鸚须룠ઠ廌焔
```

Edit 2: In response to NobodyNada, `d.base64EncodedString()` outputs

```
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
```

Which doesn't decode to anything meaningful. The data, `d`, is the result of `DCDevice.generateToken()` after confirming that the device is supported with `DCDevice.isSupported`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `d!.base64EncodedString()` please?  My guess is that your data is corrup/invalid/not a string; where are you getting it from?

Comment: @NobodyNada I added the output you requested. I'm beginning to think this API isn't fully baked quite yet.

Comment: What makes you think the token that `DCDevice` gives you is textual content at all? If it was textual content, it probably would have given you a `String`. I'm guessing the data is actually some cryptographically-signed blob.

Comment: ^ that.  `Data` is used to represent raw binary data, and does not necessarily has to decode to meaningful text.  If you need to store/transmit it as a String for some reason, you can use base64; if you need to pass it to a C API, you can use e.g. `withUnsafeBytes`; otherwise, just leave it as a `Data`.

Comment: @KevinBallard You just nailed it. I was expecting a UUID type string, digging a bit further into the server docs it is defined as `Base 64–encoded representation of encrypted device information`. Which means I'm getting what I should be getting.